# How to use Pytorch LinAlg Solver?

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra

I'm trying to replicate the first example on https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.solve.html

```
import torch
import time


Acuda = torch.randn(2,3,3,device='cuda')
bcuda = torch.randn(2,3,4,device='cuda')


t1 = time.time()
torch.linalg.torch.solve(Acuda,bcuda)

print('torch took: ',time.time()-t1)
```

As result I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "linalg_solver_test.py", line 10, in <module>
     torch.linalg.torch.solve(Acuda,bcuda) 
     RuntimeError: A must be batches of square matrices, but they are 4 by 3 matrices
```

My Pytorch Version is **1.7.1**.
In contray to the example on the documentation page, I'm using `torch.linalg.torch.solve`
as `torch.linalg.solve` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the latest PyTorch 1.9 for LinAlg, because it explicitly mentions "Major improvements to support scientific computing, including torch.linalg" (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.9.0)

PyTorch 1.7.1 is rather old. Looks like this version's LinAlg solver doesn't support non-square matrices.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the parameters A, B is actually B, A in this old version of function for solving AX = B.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.solve.html